# Regaining access to Stack Overflow account with abandoned email address

Tags: discussion

I'm trying to regain access to my old Stack Overflow account, which I have long since lost the password to. The account was created with a university email account that I no longer have access to, so the account recovery tool is of no use to me.

This might sound bad, but I can at least provide the email address, and the Stack Overflow account name matches my name. Is there any hope for me?

(I know that meta.stackoverflow would be a better place for this question, but I need 5 reputation points and this temporary account only comes with 1.)

Comment: Did you already try to [contact SO](https://stackoverflow.com/contact?referrer=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f)?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280181/ive-lost-access-to-my-se-email-and-password-do-i-have-options

Comment: For anyone finding this, I was able to regain access by contacting SO and providing enough detail for them to identify me. Thanks for the help.